# How to install apt-get dependencies in Docker image using sbt-native-packager plugin

Tags: docker, scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am using the [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) plugin to generate a Docker image for a Scala project. The project requires a specific package ***libnetcdf.so*** to be installed on the image.

I am using the below configuration on my build.sbt

```
dockerCommands ++= Seq(
  ExecCmd("RUN","sudo","apt-get","update"),
  ExecCmd("RUN","sudo","apt-get","install","-y","libnetcdf-dev")
)
```

However when generating/building the image using ***sbt docker:publishLocal*** I get the below errors.

```
[error] #18 [mainstage 6/7] RUN ["sudo", "apt-get", "update"]
[error] #18 0.358 runc run failed: unable to start container process: exec: "sudo": executable file not found in $PATH
[error] #18 ERROR: process "sudo apt-get update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
[error] ------
[error]  > [mainstage 6/7] RUN ["sudo", "apt-get", "update"]:
[error] 0.358 runc run failed: unable to start container process: exec: "sudo": executable file not found in $PATH
[error] ------
[error] Dockerfile:24
[error] --------------------
[error]   22 |     ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/docker/bin/root"]
[error]   23 |     CMD []
[error]   24 | >>> RUN ["sudo", "apt-get", "update"]
[error]   25 |     RUN ["sudo", "apt-get", "install", "-y", "libnetcdf-dev"]
[error]   26 |
[error] --------------------
[error] ERROR: failed to solve: process "sudo apt-get update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Cannot find the right way to install a dependency using the ***dockerCommands***

Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Silly enough, it turns the default base image was not a Debian-based distro. Replaced with an Ubuntu docker image and it all worked as intended. As per **@Gaël J** response it doesn't need "sudo".

Was able to figure the distribution using the below.

```
ExecCmd("RUN","cat","/etc/os-release")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `sudo`.

```
ExecCmd("RUN","apt-get","update")
```

It doesn't exist in the image as the error says.

And moreover you don't need it because the build is likely done as root user, and only switched to a non-root user at the end. (Worth checking that though, I don't know what the SBT plugin generates by default).

Comment: he there, thanks for the help. I removed sudo but got the same errors. I think it had something to do with the image itself not having apt

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular `Cmd()` objects as well as ExecCmd ones. In your `build.sbt` you can put this:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker._
              
dockerCommands := Seq(
  Cmd("RUN", "apt-get", "update"),
  Cmd("RUN", "apt-get", "-y", "upgrade"),
  Cmd("RUN", "apt-get", "install","-y","libnetcdf-dev"),
  Cmd("USER", "1000"),               
  ExecCmd("ENTRYPOINT", "/app/docker/bin/my-app")
)
```